# Debugging maven app in eclipse throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, maven

I'm using Eclipse Kepler SR2 and Windows 7, built-in Maven Plugin.

I'm trying to debug a standalone Java app, so I opened the class which contains my main method, right click the main method on Outline view, Debug As->Java Application.

The project is on the maven default structure, containing src-main-java with the Java source files and src-main-resources with the config files, such as log4j.properties.

```
src
-main
 -java
  -packages...
 -resources
  -log4j.properties
  -conf.properties
```

The problem is when I try to open the log4j.properties:

```
org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

Or the conf.properties:

```
FileInputStream confFile = new FileInputStream("conf.properties");
```

I get a FileNotFoundException.

I tried to clean the project before debugging and also tried to run a maven clean compile, with no luck.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that your resources folder is also one of your project's source folders.  Maven knows that, but you're running the app just within Eclipse with no help from maven.

Comment: The resources folders is on my source folders (Build Path), with no exclusions...